# What voodoo sorcery coming from Teamviewer (disabling other remote access applications)?

Tags: remote-desktop, teamviewer

I've searched plenty but have not found much discussion about this voodoo...

Teamviewer [TV] (probably starting from version 14) blocks usage of other remote desktop (Anydesk=[AD]) or screen sharing (Mikogo=[Mo], Quick Assist=[QA]) applications. (recent test reveals affecting version 13 too)

I hate all the nags from Teamviewer, even while connecting no more than 1 minute. So, I would use a screen sharing application such as [Mo]. What I would do is as follows:

-----on local PC [windows 10]:
1.Launch [Mo] and generate a remote control session ID to give to remote PC later
2.Connect using [TV] to remote PC [over the internet]

-----on remote PC [windows 10/8.1]:
3. via [TV] session, open [Mo] and join established session with ID, allowing to screen sharing with local PC
4. close [TV] connection

As a result, can remote control via [Mo] session alone. This has been working for the past year, until recently. Now, after closing [TV] connection, step 4, the [Mo] session becomes blank/black with a banner message "you are unable to view the remote computer's screen. The remote computer may require local input in order to continue" or shows the remote screen but unresponsive to keyboard or mouse. Only after reconnecting [TV] would the [Mo] session return to the locked sign and becomes responsive normally again.

Similar situation with AnyDesk, where the session screen is displayed but the mouse cursor and keyboard are unresponsive. As for Quick Assist on a remote Windows 10 PC, it worked the first time using it. Subsequent times, similar unresponsive [black?] screen appears with no banner text message.

What is Teamviewer doing that disables use of another remote control or screen sharing program?

Comment: I don't think it's teamviewer to blame here. More sounds like the weakness of your other tools: they seems to work only when remote computer is attended by a person and a TV confection gives them this feeling.

Comment: Could it be a Windows issue? Do you have the same problem when using AD+Mo instead of TV+Mo?

Comment: @ Máté Juhász :  The other tools mentioned have always been working through these steps for over a year, until recently.  All the remote computers are unattended.

Comment: 1 of 3 remote PCs tested does not seem to have this issue. I think I need to put a hold on this question post while i can find additional opportunities to test. I don't always have access to these PCs. I'll be back when I get more results (perhaps next week). Thanks

Comment: If the remote PC is unattended, why not use the builtin Remote Desktop facility that works. And get rid of unreliable 3rd party tools at the same time?